# While statement ignoring function

Tags: python

I am very new to using classes and creating functions within it. I have been trying to write a bit more elegant code to the point where the only line to be 'executed' is 1 line, 'o.pag' in this case.

However, my **pag** function is just not working out. To my eyes, though I've made several variations of the same and even tried to turn it into an series of 'if' statements, gets stuck on "Would you like to play again'?.

Here the problematic but:

```
    def pag(self):
    o.game()
    o.q()
    while p_again == 'yes':
         o.game()
         o.q().  <<<<<<THIS IS WANT WONT EXECUTE AFTER TYPING 'YES'
         if p_again != 'yes':
             break
```

Here is the complete code sample. I am wondering if I caused the problem myself by trying to put everything into functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import random

a = random.randint(1, 9)
#a = 4
again = ''
y = 'yes'
n = 'no'
g= 0
p_again = ''


class olv(object):    
    def glogic(self):
        if g > a:
            print('You guessed too HIGH.')
        elif g < a:
            print('You guessed too LOW.')
        else:
            print(g)
        
    
        
    
    def game(self):
        global g
        while g != a:
            g = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 9! '))
            o.glogic()
            if g == a:
                print('Wow, you guessed it.')
            
    def q(self):
        global p_again
        p_again = str(input('Would you like to play again?  '))
            
    def pag(self):
        o.game()
        o.q()
        while p_again == 'yes':
             o.game()
             o.q()
             if p_again != 'yes':
                 break
        
o = olv()
        
o.pag()
```

Comment: stuck how? you input "yes", press Enter, but the game doesn't start over again?

Comment: You are doing well, but you miss some points, the code is a bit messy.
First thing: don't define variables outside your class (globals).
If you create variables inside methods using `self.varname = ...` than you can retrieve them from other methods.

Comment: on that code as is, if you enter 'yes' it does not re-run the guessing game again. It just asks over and over 'Do you want to play again' until you enter something else.

I appreciate the feedback about the variables. Doing a lot of learn as you go here. I did not think about entering variables after creating teh class.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put in inside function not out side the function.
code should look like this.

```
def pag(self):
    o.game()
    o.q()
    while p_again == 'yes':
         o.game()
         o.q().  <<<<<<THIS IS WANT WONT EXECUTE AFTER TYPING 'YES'
         if p_again != 'yes':
             break
```

Comment: He put there while loop code to outside the function I rewrite code that show that code should have inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

### Just what you asked for

The problem manifests like this:

1. You play the game until you guessed the right number. Note that `g == a` now.
2. The asks "Do you want to play again?"
3. `game()` is called
4. But since `g == a`, `game()` will immediately quit

So, what's the problem? Well, for a new game, `a` needs to get a new random value.

### Other stuff to make you a better programmer

1. To me it looks like you're typing in a poor text editor. You use short variable names. If you use an IDE which is made for Python, you'll get code completion and you can have better names that actually express what things are. `a` could be `answer`, `g` could be `guess` etc. Try JetBrains PyCharm. They have a community edition which is already great.
2. To me, `glogic()` is incomplete. The "Wow you guessed it" part is in `game()`. How about

   ```
    def glogic(self):
        if g > a:
            print('You guessed too HIGH.')
        elif g < a:
            print('You guessed too LOW.')
        else:
            print('Wow, you guessed it.')
   ```
3. The code depends on global variables. Since you already have a class, all the variables could be included there. Please read about `def __init__(self)` and member variables like `self.answer` etc.
4. In `q()`, you convert the user input into a string. That's unnecessary, because it is already a string.
5. In `pag()`, code is duplicate. The logic to execute `o.game()` and then `o.q()` is coded twice. If you set `p_again = "yes"` initially, you can get rid of that duplication.
6. It seems `n`, `y` and `again` are unused.
7. To make user input a bit more robust, you could `.lower()` the input just in case the user enters some captital letters.
8. Same for numbers: if the user enters a letter, the code will fail with a `ValueError`. Use `try: ... except ValueError: ...` to make the game more robust.

I could rewrite the whole code for you, but I think it's worth doing that yourself.

Comment: Hey Thomas,

This was super helpful. Thank you for the tip about the __init__ bit. I have seen this in a lot of places but sure don't get it's function. Will do some reading about it.

I'll re-work based on your feedback. The bit of the top about the logic is sure what I was missing. Thank you for singling this out.

Answer (score 0):

I believed that this guessing game can run without using classes. From your code, it shows that your basics towards classes is not familiar enough.

You can try to make this guessing game without using classes first. Then you can try to implement the game using classes.

Here is an example of using classes for this game:

```
import random

p_again = ""
class olv:
    def __init__(self):
        self.answer = random.randint(1, 9)
        self.guess = 0

    def game(self):
        while self.guess != self.answer:
            self.guess = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 9: '))
            if self.guess > self.answer:
                print('You guessed too HIGH.')
            elif self.guess < self.answer:
                print('You guessed too LOW.')
            elif self.guess == self.answer:
                print("Wow, you guessed it")
            else:
                print("You should guess between 1 and 9")


while True:
    o = olv()
    o.game()
    p_again = str(input('Would you like to play again?  ')).lower()
    if p_again != "yes":
        break
```

Comment: Totally, I had in fact made it work without classes. But that was sort of the 'next challenge' and how I ended up with the mess above. Thanks for the help. Still getting familiar with this 'new method' (to me). Some reading to go too. Hadn't used that "while True" before either.

Comment: OOP is very important in programming. Try to look for more online content and implement more, then you will be more familiar to OOP. I also used a lot of time at first.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you have most of the code logic in there; however there is some confusion about OOP. One great thing to learn is to abandon (at least mostly) global variables, and use classes so that they can keep state of things. Another great suggestion I have is to use meaningful names, for variables and methods.

Now, it is a bit difficult to comment on each line of your code, so I took the liberty to rewrite it a bit. Keep in mind, there are dozen ways to do the same thing, so mine is not the best, nor (hopefully) the worse. I'll add comments to the code:

```
import random

class Game(object):
    # First, let's use meaningful names

    def __init__(self):
        # Being a class, we can have an init method, and we can use it to initialize
        # some variables that we will use to maintain "state". This means, we will give
        # the class the job to remember what these values are during the course of the
        # program, instead of storing them as global variables
        #
        # These variables are accessible by ALL methods in the class, using `self.`

        self.value_to_guess = -1    # Note: we make value_to_guess and user_input different on purpose
        self.user_input = 0         #       so that play_game can loop without too much extra code
        self.continue_play = True

    def game_logic(self):
        # This method is in charge of the game logic, which is "compare the values and print something"
        # In your original code you did it for only two cases (>, <); it would be a good idea to also
        # consolidate the case of equality

        if self.user_input > self.value_to_guess:
            print('You guessed too HIGH.')

        elif self.user_input < self.value_to_guess:
            print('You guessed too LOW.')

        else:
            print('Wow, you guessed it.')

    def game_play(self):
        # This method is in charge of the game play, making sure that a new random value is
        # set at the beginning of a cycle, and that the user is asked every time for a value,
        # until the user guesses. Every time, `game_logic` is called so that it will print the
        # appropriate message on screen
        #
        self.value_to_guess = random.randint(1, 9)
        while self.value_to_guess != self.user_input:
            self.user_input = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 9! '))
            self.game_logic()

    def question(self):
        # This method will ask the user the question, and return the answered string straight out
        return str(input('Would you like to play again?  '))

    def play(self):
        # This method in charge of running games+questions, until the user stops answering 'yes'

        self.game_play()
        while self.question() == 'yes':
            self.game_play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_game = Game()    # Create a new Game object
    my_game.play()      # Ask the game object `my_game` to start playing
```

It's a lot of code, but I hope all the comments will help.